# Emit raw html in ASP page?

Tags: html, asp-classic, templating

This is extremely aggravating. I just want to simply insert raw html. I can't use the literal control because there's no ignoring the quote character. I don't want to use a script element because I'm adding it in a ascx file. I just want raw html output. Is there no operater for this?

Answer (score 1):

I've properbly misunderstood you completely but:

In Classic ASP it is:

```
<%=("<div style=""color:red;"">html</div>")%>
```

output:

```
<div style="color:red;">html</div>
```